# Paper-toast not showing

Tags: polymer

I am trying to display a toast when an ajax request fails using *core-ajax* and *paper-toast* elements. I created an handler that calls show on the *paper-toast* element. However it is still not showing...
What am I doing wrong? 
Is there a better way to do that? (Maybe having the same toast element for all the application messages)

Here it follows my custom element code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">

<polymer-element name="fd-rest-element-service" attributes="fditems fdtype">
  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
    paper-toast {
      z-index: 1000;
      bottom: 40px;
      left: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    <paper-toast id="toast" text="There was a problem loading {{fdtype}} data.">
    </paper-toast>
    <core-ajax id="ajax" 
      auto on-core-error="{{errorHandler}}"
      url="https://wrong.url.com:9113/{{fdtype}}/"
      disabled-on-core-response="{{elementsLoaded}}"
      response="{{fditems}}"
      handleAs="json"  withCredentials >
    </core-ajax>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('fd-rest-element-service', {

    fdtype:'environments',

    created: function() {
      this.fditems = [];
    },

    elementsLoaded: function() {
      // Make a copy of the loaded data
      console.log(this.fdtype +" : "+ this.$.ajax.response);
      this.fditems = this.$.ajax.response.slice(0);

    },

    errorHandler: function(event){
      console.log(event);
      console.log(this.$.toast);
      this.$.toast.show();
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Since I have got no console error and the logged objects are as expected I believe the problem arises because the element is used inside an element managed by *core-animated-pages* that is not displayed. Any suggestion on how to create a shared toast element that can be accessed by the other elements in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating the *paper-toast* element inside the outmost element and then pass it through the children element via a *toast* attribute.

Here it follows some sample code. In my root element I created a *paper-toast* element referenced by id and share "top-down" in the other inner elements.

```
<paper-toast 
  id="toast" 
  text="There was a problem loading data.">
</paper-toast>

<fow-login user="{{user}}" userPhoto="{{userPhoto}}"
    class="loginButton"
    toast="{{$.toast}}"
    token="{{token}}">
</fow-login>
```

In my inner element I use it like this:

```
<polymer-element name="fow-login" attributes="toast user userPhoto globals appID token">
...
<script>
...
loginFail: function(event){
      console.log("Error:", event);
      if(this.toast){
        this.toast.text="There was a login problem.";
        this.toast.show();
      }
    },
...
</script>
</polymer-element>
```